# Setting Up a Multiplatform Project

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

considering `Kotlin 1.2` introduced `kotlin-platform-common` I'm trying to build my first common `.class` file, so I did the below:

`main.kt`:

```
package hello

fun main() {
    println("kotlin!")
}
```

`gradle.build`:

```
group 'h'
version 'prn'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-common'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/kotlin'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'src/resources'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'hello.MainKt'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Then I run `gradle build`

Q1- I coud not find any `.class` file generated? how to get it generated and where should I find it?

Q2- I got a `.jar` file generated, but once I tried to run it, I got an error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class hello.MainKt

I tried to run it using the below 2 option, but got the same error for bot:

Option 1:

```
kotlin -cp <filename>.jar hello.MainKt
```

Option 2:

```
java -jar <filename>.jar
```

Project structure, and errors are as in this pic below:

[image]

Comment: This is an invalid main method signature

Comment: @1blustone I got the same, though I changed it to be `fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("kotlin!")
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Kotlin 1.2, common modules don't generate binaries (like .class files), only metadata files. This is true **even if you don't use the `expect` keyword anywhere**.

So you have to create another module which includes something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-jvm'
```

The JVM modules will also need an `expectedBy` entry in `dependencies` for your common module. Plus you'll probably want a corresponding JS module of course.

It's probably best to let IntelliJ create the whole multiplatform project for you and then edit the Gradle files to suit, but this page lists the manual steps: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html#setting-up-a-multiplatform-project